# What are the basics of Kilikki, the language of Kalkeyas?

Tags: dialogue, baahubali-the-beginning

For the film Bahubali: The Beginning, a new language called 'Kilikki' was developed and during the war Bahubali and others needed a translator to communicate with those invaders Kalakeyas. I recently heard that their language has its own grammar rules and words.

I would like to understand the basics of this language. So my question, Is there any resources available for understanding this language 'Kilikki'? A few examples, words or sentences, will be really helpful.

Comment: English : good morning Kilikili : kulla kussa tha tha English good afternoon Kilikili : kulla kussa Bussa that tha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few resources around about the constructed language Kilikili (or Kiliki), according to the article [5 Sentences And Their Translations In Kiliki, The Fictitious Language Used In 'Baahubali'](http://www.huffingtonpost.in/2015/07/14/baahubali-language-kiliki_n_7792878.html), the language has over 750 words and over 40 grammar rules. This language was based on an earlier language (Cliq) the author did as a thought exercise of sorts.

A grammar rule includes:

> including two different kind of 'click' sounds — one that denotes a plural (the sound one makes to express disapproval) and another that indicates a possessive (the sound you make if you try and pronounce a hard 'T' without actually saying it out loud).

Additionally, the author of the language wanted to portray the emotion behind the words, with:

> "I used hard consonants and soft consonants depending on whether the word was 'hard' or 'soft'," he said. For example, the Kiliki word for 'blood' is 'brrusla', with emphasis on the rolled Rs to make it sound primal and aggressive.

A few sentences featured in the article are:

> > 1.
>
> English: He should be alive.
>
> Kiliki: Ta beet-qruvool dunkra.
>
> 2.
>
> English: Is it true?
>
> Kiliki: Loursha-quay?
>
> 3.
>
> English: Drop your weapons in the field and run away.
>
> Kiliki: Nim*kle gadeetvoo*tta corota-jra reyy... fuhoo*kle.
>
> (* denotes the click sound for either plural or possessive, as per the
>   context)
>
> 4.
>
> English: Can you give me a cup of water?
>
> Kiliki: Nim shweek min surrp unoa dhab saasslaa finhee-quay?
>
> 5.
>
> English: Don’t talk like a fool.
>
> Kiliki: Dambadamba jivla baahaa-na.

A [YouTube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNCw2yWVpbw) of one of the main actors speaking in Kilikili is available.