# Is Mahabali's tribal language a meaningful language like Kilikki?

Tags: dialogue, baahubali-the-lost-legends

In *Baahubali: The Lost Legends* season 4 we meet Mahabali's tribe and they were using their secret language which was forbidden to be taught to anyone outside the tribe.

Is this language also a meaningful language like [Kilikki](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/37388/what-are-the-basics-of-kilikki-the-language-of-kalkeyas) and has some basics or is it random nonsensical words?

Comment: isn't every language meaningful when you understand it?

Comment: @Vishwa I didn't understand Kilikki either when I heard in the movie later got to know they made a proper language for the film